# Setting Focus to TextBox from Other UserControl inside a Canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, caliburn.micro

I am using a Canvas inside a Window, to make it like a MDI Application.

The canvas will hold multiple UserControls which are Child Windows.

I am able to open a new UserControl inside the Canvas on the GotFocus event of some textbox.

But When I Click Enter or closes the new Window, I want to set the focus back to the old UserControl's next TextBox? Which I am not able to achieve.

I am using WPF with Caliburn Micro? Currently using EventAggreagator to open the new UserControl on GotFocus event of TextBox.

Comment: Is it possible to create a Behaviour for this

Answer (score 1):

I recently did something similar and the only thing I could come up with was to use the `IEventAggregator` to publish a notification that a UserControl had closed, i.e.,

```
public class ControlClosedEvent
{
    public ControlClosedEvent()
    {
        // can be an empty event for all intents and purposes
    }
}
```

Whenever a UserControl closes, publish the event:

```
 _events.Publish( new ControlClosedEvent() );
```

And the consumers:

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl, IHandle<ControlClosedEvent>
{
    public void Handle( ControlClosedEvent message )
    {
        // ugly way of setting the text box as focused
        SomeTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i have tried so far...but has the issue to set the focus

Comment: FocusManager is not working, since my window is inside an Canvas